# Unable to load preferences into list with PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement new google's `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. 
I made it like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
```

It also can be done in onCreate method.

**Question 1.** 
(What's the difference?)

I have a `PreferenceScreen` in `R.xml.settings`.

I also have (`R.layout.fragment_settings`):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
}
```

with `android:id="@android:id/list"` in it. On Regular `PreferenceFragment` this method works and loads my `Preferences` into this list.
But now, I have this error:

```
10-02 12:10:20.064  23270-23270/ru.intercom18.IntercomMWP E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.intercom18.IntercomMWP, PID: 23270
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.bindPreferences(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:466)
        at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onActivityCreated(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:271)
```

**Question 2.** 
(How should I load PreferenceScreen into list in my custom settings_fragment.xml)

Comment: your view on which you are calling the setAdapter function is null

Comment: Secondly....Please read the ethics and the guidelines to ask a question(nothing to demotivate you, but you maintain decorum on SOverflow). Oh, this comment is in regard with your WTF written at the last which i have now removed, thanks to edits :D

Comment: O, really? And I was wondering what that means setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference. Have you ever worked with PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Comment: in that case, see this tutorial on how to use it , https://guides.codepath.com/android/Settings-with-PreferenceFragment, Not much that's why this link and no answer.